# Using db_select with subqueries

Tags: 7, database

Here's an example raw query of what I am trying to achieve with database API:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      n.nid AS entity_id,
      n.uid,
      n.title,
      node_body.body_value,
      node_body.body_format,
      'node' AS entity_type
    FROM
      `node` n,
      `field_data_body` node_body
    WHERE
      n.status = 1 AND
      n.type = 'forum' AND
      n.nid = node_body.entity_id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT
      c.cid,
      c.uid,
      '-' AS subject,
      comment_body.comment_body_value,
      comment_body.comment_body_format,
      'comment' AS entity_type
    FROM
      `node` n,
      `comment` c,
      `field_data_comment_body` comment_body
    WHERE
      c.nid = n.nid AND
      n.status = 1 AND
      n.type = 'forum' AND
      c.cid = comment_body.entity_id
) AS results ORDER BY results.entity_id
```

I have to do this using `db_select()` because of the pager.

My question is: how can I use `db_select()` for selecting results that are *not* from a specific table, but from subqueries like the query above?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you can't, unless you add subqueries created with db_select (or objectively). Have you seen [this](https://api.drupal.org/comment/17859#comment-17859) and tried to play with it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I was afraid of - I was thinking of having a bogus query in the main `db_query()` and then adding the real query through an expression or a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a modified question on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53136) site and the solution was to simply use a DB view instead.

Here is the code I ended up using:

`MYMODULE.install` file:

```
function MYMODULE_install() {
  db_query("CREATE VIEW {MYMODULE_view_sample}
              SELECT
                n.nid AS entity_id,
                n.uid,
                n.title,
                node_body.body_value,
                node_body.body_format,
                'node' AS entity_type
              FROM
                {node} n,
                {field_data_body} node_body
              WHERE
                n.status = 1 AND
                n.type = 'forum' AND
                n.nid = node_body.entity_id
            UNION ALL
              SELECT
                c.cid,
                c.uid,
                '-' AS subject,
                comment_body.comment_body_value,
                comment_body.comment_body_format,
                'comment' AS entity_type
              FROM
                {node} n,
                {comment} c,
                {field_data_comment_body} comment_body
              WHERE
                c.nid = n.nid AND
                n.status = 1 AND
                n.type = 'forum' AND
                c.cid = comment_body.entity_id");
}

function MYMODULE_uninstall() {
  // Remove the view once the module is uninstalled.
  db_query("DROP VIEW {MYMODULE_view_sample}");
}
```

And then simply browse it as if it was another table:

```
$query = db_select('MYMODULE_view_sample', 's');
$query = $query
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(10);
$query->fields('s');
$results = $query->execute();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  dpm($result);
}
```

Thanks to everyone posting here.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can prepare a SelectQuery object using db_select(), then use it in place of a table in another db_select(). Example (off-the-cuff, not tested):

```
$inner_query = db_select('comment', 'c')
  ->fields('c');
$outer_query = db_select($inner_query, 'sub');
```

Second of all, you can UNION two prepared SelectQuery objects with the SelectQuery::union() method.

```
$some_query = db_select('comment_table', c)->fields('c');
$union_query = db_select('other_comment_table', o)->fields('o')->union($some_query, 'ALL');
```

So all the tools you need are there; it'll just take some trial and error to put them all together.

Comment: Great solutions, but I don't think the exact query the OP's looking for is possible with the core `SelectQuery`. Specifically, there's no way to get `SELECT *` at the beginning of the query as far as I can tell (unless you can assign an alias to the chain of `UNION`s and force it to select `results.*`). It looks like a table and/or field alias will always be added to the expression. Subclassing `SelectQuery` to do it would be a pretty quick job though

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I started playing around with this - will post back shortly.

Comment: @Clive could you elaborate a bit more please? Do you have any link to more information/example?

Comment: @LesLim seems this can't directly answer the question; the main problem is exactly what Clive mentioned - I can't get the `SELECT *` in front of everything, which is essential as I want to mix results of nodes and comments. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in any case :)